# Nodejs http.ClientRequest socket not working with 'data' event (paused/flowing mode?)

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, node.js-stream

I am studying the code from Node.js http module document https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect_1 . The original code prints http response data on the screen. After I move the 'data' event callback from place (A) to (B), it only prints the connection headers `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established ...` but no http body. The program just halts there. Is it the socket doesn't emit 'data' event or what reason? It seems the socket doesn't emit 'end' event either.

I fixed the problem by adding code (C), forcing the socket to work in flowing mode. But I don't understand why it doesn't work without code (C).

The client part code is as following:

```
// make a request to a tunneling proxy
var options = {
    port: 1337,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80'
};

var req = http.request(options);
req.end();

req.on('socket', function(res, socket, head) {  // Added for learning
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {    // (B)
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
    // socket.resume();    // (C) FIX
});

req.on('connect', function(res, socket, head) {
    console.log('got connected!');

    // make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
                 'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
                 'Connection: close\r\n' +
                 '\r\n');
    // socket.on('data', function(chunk) {    // (A)
    //     console.log(chunk.toString());
    // });
    socket.on('end', function() {
        proxy.close();
    });
});
```

The full and originally code is here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect_1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason why (A) works and (B) doesn't is because (A) assigned a listener to data event after you wrote to the socket. When (B) assigns a listener to data event, it happens before socket.write is called. When socket.write is called it pauses the socket,  so socket.resume() resumes data reading mode. I recommend you to use new stream API though, since it's a lot more intuitive and flexible (https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will not use the old stream API. Just for fun, I want to figure out when the socket paused. I read the 'Stream Handbook' and I dig into node.js source (net module and stream module), but I can't find where it pauses the socket. Would you list the source or link(with source row number)? And if I want to debug such a problem, how to do the debug?

Comment: I've never had to go to node.js source, so I don't know where to look for a logic that pauses your stream ( it probably even could be on a C++ level ). To debug it you could use node-inspector. You could set break points in both callbacks and see which one fires first and what happens when certain methods of the stream get called. BTW, I didn't actually run your code. I just assumed what may be the reason, provided your code and the explanation.